# Apache htaccess sending URLs in a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to send a URL in a URL, and there's ModRewrite in the middle.

Here's the Rewrite Rule. It's used to search for a user's profile.

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(query)/(profile)/([a-z0-9:.()\-\ ]+)/?$ search/index.php?scope=$2&query=$3 [NC,L]`

And this is the URL

`http://www.example.com/query/profile/http://www.facebook.com/example`

No matter how I do the rewrite rule, I keep getting `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error` or `NetworkError: 404 Not Found` if it's a URL I put there.

How can I do this right? I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium. Am I missing something?

The URL above is passed using ajax.

**Edit:**

```
#htaccess in site1 folder
RewriteRule ^resources/?(.*)/?$ /control/$1 [NC,L]

#htaccess in control folder
RewriteRule ^(query)/(profile)/([a-z0-9:.()\-\ ]+)/?$ search/index.php?scope=$2&query=$3 [NC,L]

next folder is `search` which has `index.php`

URL used
http://www.example.com/resources/query/profile/http://www.facebook.com/example
```

**EDIT:**
I redid the RewriteRule like below, and don't get any error messages now, but Apache seems to be taking off one `/` from the url after the `http://`. So I get only `http:/www.facebook.com/example`. Any help with that will be appreciated.

```
RewriteRule ^(query)/(profile)/([a-z0-9\/:.()\-\ ]+)/?$ search/index.php?scope=$2&query=$3 [NC,L]`
```

Comment: can you post from what url you want to rewrite to what url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture URL from `RewriteCond` otherwise Apache will trim multiple `//` into a single one.

Change this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /resources/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /control/%1 [L]
```

Have this in `/control/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /control/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(query)/(profile)/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /resources/search/index.php?scope=%2&query=%3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The `RewriteBase /`gives me a `404` error. I think that's because my .htaccess is inside a folder called search. Without the `RewriteBase /`I still get a `404`

Comment: And, you're correct about Apache trimming multiple `//`

Comment: No. It's not. It's like this - `site1/resources/search/.htaccess`

Comment: I seem to be getting it right almost, except for Apache removing the `//` to `/`

Comment: Actually, there's a `.htaccess` in the root (site1) that passes all url's with `query` to the folder `resources` from were it's handle the way it's done above.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Works this time, but not as expected. Apache still removes one `/` from the url, making it useless.

Comment: That is due to same problem in root .htaccess (see updated answer).

Comment: Aah! Finally. Worked this time. Thank you, Anubhava. You're a good guy... always there to help with htaccess :-)